# Filter out info in a column of a DataFrame into 3 new columns in that same DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe where one of the columns is called `structure` and contains large objects, an example of which is below.

```
('structure', Structure Summary
Lattice
 abc : 3.44648958 5.91809299 11.43413371
 angles : 90.0 90.0 90.0
 volume : 233.21797558148117
      A : 3.44648958 0.0 0.0
      B : 0.0 5.91809299 0.0
      C : 0.0 -0.0 11.43413371
PeriodicSite: Y (0.0000, 2.2193, 7.4375) [0.0000, 0.3750, 0.6505]
PeriodicSite: Y (0.0000, 3.6988, 3.9966) [-0.0000, 0.6250, 0.3495]
PeriodicSite: Y (0.0000, 5.1783, 9.7137) [0.0000, 0.8750, 0.8495]
PeriodicSite: Y (0.0000, 0.7398, 1.7205) [-0.0000, 0.1250, 0.1505]
PeriodicSite: Cr (0.0000, 2.2441, 10.5351) [-0.0000, 0.3792, 0.9214]
PeriodicSite: Cr (0.0000, 3.6740, 0.8991) [0.0000, 0.6208, 0.0786]
PeriodicSite: Cr (0.0000, 5.2031, 6.6161) [0.0000, 0.8792, 0.5786]
PeriodicSite: Cr (0.0000, 0.7150, 4.8180) [0.0000, 0.1208, 0.4214]
PeriodicSite: B (1.7232, 0.1461, 7.9047) [0.5000, 0.0247, 0.6913]
PeriodicSite: B (1.7232, 5.7720, 3.5294) [0.5000, 0.9753, 0.3087]
PeriodicSite: B (1.7232, 3.1051, 9.2465) [0.5000, 0.5247, 0.8087]
PeriodicSite: B (1.7232, 2.8130, 2.1876) [0.5000, 0.4753, 0.1913]
PeriodicSite: B (1.7232, 0.6689, 6.2512) [0.5000, 0.1130, 0.5467]
PeriodicSite: B (1.7232, 5.2492, 5.1829) [0.5000, 0.8870, 0.4533]
PeriodicSite: B (1.7232, 3.6280, 10.9000) [0.5000, 0.6130, 0.9533]
PeriodicSite: B (1.7232, 2.2901, 0.5342) [0.5000, 0.3870, 0.0467]
PeriodicSite: B (1.7232, 1.6549, 3.6187) [0.5000, 0.2796, 0.3165]
PeriodicSite: B (1.7232, 4.2632, 7.8154) [0.5000, 0.7204, 0.6835]
PeriodicSite: B (1.7232, 4.6139, 2.0984) [0.5000, 0.7796, 0.1835]
PeriodicSite: B (1.7232, 1.3041, 9.3358) [0.5000, 0.2204, 0.8165]
PeriodicSite: B (1.7232, 2.1437, 5.3450) [0.5000, 0.3622, 0.4675]
PeriodicSite: B (1.7232, 3.7743, 6.0891) [0.5000, 0.6378, 0.5325]
PeriodicSite: B (1.7232, 5.1028, 0.3721) [0.5000, 0.8622, 0.0325]
PeriodicSite: B (1.7232, 0.8153, 11.0621) [0.5000, 0.1378, 0.9675])
```

Here is an example code with the first 2 columns of the dataframe as a dictionary.

```py
import pandas
dict = df['structure'].to_dict()
print(dict)
ex_dict = {
0: "('structure', Structure Summary\nLattice\n    abc : 3.44648958 5.91809299 11.43413371\n angles : 90.0 90.0 90.0\n volume : 233.21797558148117\n      A : 3.44648958 0.0 0.0\n      B : 0.0 5.91809299 0.0\n      C : 0.0 -0.0 11.43413371\nPeriodicSite: Y (0.0000, 2.2193, 7.4375) [0.0000, 0.3750, 0.6505]\nPeriodicSite: Y (0.0000, 3.6988, 3.9966) [-0.0000, 0.6250, 0.3495]\nPeriodicSite: Y (0.0000, 5.1783, 9.7137) [0.0000, 0.8750, 0.8495]\nPeriodicSite: Y (0.0000, 0.7398, 1.7205) [-0.0000, 0.1250, 0.1505]\nPeriodicSite: Cr (0.0000, 2.2441, 10.5351) [-0.0000, 0.3792, 0.9214]\nPeriodicSite: Cr (0.0000, 3.6740, 0.8991) [0.0000, 0.6208, 0.0786]\nPeriodicSite: Cr (0.0000, 5.2031, 6.6161) [0.0000, 0.8792, 0.5786]\nPeriodicSite: Cr (0.0000, 0.7150, 4.8180) [0.0000, 0.1208, 0.4214]\nPeriodicSite: B (1.7232, 0.1461, 7.9047) [0.5000, 0.0247, 0.6913]\nPeriodicSite: B (1.7232, 5.7720, 3.5294) [0.5000, 0.9753, 0.3087]\nPeriodicSite: B (1.7232, 3.1051, 9.2465) [0.5000, 0.5247, 0.8087]\nPeriodicSite: B (1.7232, 2.8130, 2.1876) [0.5000, 0.4753, 0.1913]\nPeriodicSite: B (1.7232, 0.6689, 6.2512) [0.5000, 0.1130, 0.5467]\nPeriodicSite: B (1.7232, 5.2492, 5.1829) [0.5000, 0.8870, 0.4533]\nPeriodicSite: B (1.7232, 3.6280, 10.9000) [0.5000, 0.6130, 0.9533]\nPeriodicSite: B (1.7232, 2.2901, 0.5342) [0.5000, 0.3870, 0.0467]\nPeriodicSite: B (1.7232, 1.6549, 3.6187) [0.5000, 0.2796, 0.3165]\nPeriodicSite: B (1.7232, 4.2632, 7.8154) [0.5000, 0.7204, 0.6835]\nPeriodicSite: B (1.7232, 4.6139, 2.0984) [0.5000, 0.7796, 0.1835]\nPeriodicSite: B (1.7232, 1.3041, 9.3358) [0.5000, 0.2204, 0.8165]\nPeriodicSite: B (1.7232, 2.1437, 5.3450) [0.5000, 0.3622, 0.4675]\nPeriodicSite: B (1.7232, 3.7743, 6.0891) [0.5000, 0.6378, 0.5325]\nPeriodicSite: B (1.7232, 5.1028, 0.3721) [0.5000, 0.8622, 0.0325]\nPeriodicSite: B (1.7232, 0.8153, 11.0621) [0.5000, 0.1378, 0.9675])"
        , 1: "('structure', Structure Summary\nLattice\n    abc : 3.738665247991437 3.738665247991437 3.61051776\n angles : 90.0 90.0 106.27565704267273\n volume : 48.44396724150258\n      A : 2.24279581 -2.99123466 0.0\n      B : 2.24279581 2.99123466 0.0\n      C : 0.0 0.0 3.61051776\nPeriodicSite: Y (2.2428, 2.9725, 0.0000) [0.0031, 0.9969, -0.0000]\nPeriodicSite: Ni (2.2428, -0.6786, 1.8053) [0.6134, 0.3866, 0.5000]\nPeriodicSite: C (2.9274, 1.1773, 1.8053) [0.4558, 0.8494, 0.5000]\nPeriodicSite: C (1.5582, 1.1773, 1.8053) [0.1506, 0.5442, 0.5000])"}
```

I want to take the `a`, `b`, and `c` lattice parameter floats:

> **3.44648958**, **5.91809299**, **11.43413371**

And have them appear as 3 columns in a new dataframe that I can then add onto the original one. Example code below.

```py
result_dict = {'a' : [3.44648958, 3.738665247991437], 'b' : [5.91809299, 3.738665247991437], 'c' : [11.43413371, 3.61051776]}
result_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(result_dict)
print(result_df)
```

Not sure where to even start.

Comment: Difficult to answer without the code to reproduce your object…

Comment: I added some example code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the following dataframe you provided:

```py
import pandas as pd

ex_dict = {
    "structure": [
        "('structure', Structure Summary\nLattice\n    abc : 3.44648958 5.91809299 11.43413371\n angles : 90.0 90.0 90.0\n volume : 233.21797558148117\n      A : 3.44648958 0.0 0.0\n      B : 0.0 5.91809299 0.0\n      C : 0.0 -0.0 11.43413371\nPeriodicSite: Y (0.0000, 2.2193, 7.4375) [0.0000, 0.3750, 0.6505]\nPeriodicSite: Y (0.0000, 3.6988, 3.9966) [-0.0000, 0.6250, 0.3495]\nPeriodicSite: Y (0.0000, 5.1783, 9.7137) [0.0000, 0.8750, 0.8495]\nPeriodicSite: Y (0.0000, 0.7398, 1.7205) [-0.0000, 0.1250, 0.1505]\nPeriodicSite: Cr (0.0000, 2.2441, 10.5351) [-0.0000, 0.3792, 0.9214]\nPeriodicSite: Cr (0.0000, 3.6740, 0.8991) [0.0000, 0.6208, 0.0786]\nPeriodicSite: Cr (0.0000, 5.2031, 6.6161) [0.0000, 0.8792, 0.5786]\nPeriodicSite: Cr (0.0000, 0.7150, 4.8180) [0.0000, 0.1208, 0.4214]\nPeriodicSite: B (1.7232, 0.1461, 7.9047) [0.5000, 0.0247, 0.6913]\nPeriodicSite: B (1.7232, 5.7720, 3.5294) [0.5000, 0.9753, 0.3087]\nPeriodicSite: B (1.7232, 3.1051, 9.2465) [0.5000, 0.5247, 0.8087]\nPeriodicSite: B (1.7232, 2.8130, 2.1876) [0.5000, 0.4753, 0.1913]\nPeriodicSite: B (1.7232, 0.6689, 6.2512) [0.5000, 0.1130, 0.5467]\nPeriodicSite: B (1.7232, 5.2492, 5.1829) [0.5000, 0.8870, 0.4533]\nPeriodicSite: B (1.7232, 3.6280, 10.9000) [0.5000, 0.6130, 0.9533]\nPeriodicSite: B (1.7232, 2.2901, 0.5342) [0.5000, 0.3870, 0.0467]\nPeriodicSite: B (1.7232, 1.6549, 3.6187) [0.5000, 0.2796, 0.3165]\nPeriodicSite: B (1.7232, 4.2632, 7.8154) [0.5000, 0.7204, 0.6835]\nPeriodicSite: B (1.7232, 4.6139, 2.0984) [0.5000, 0.7796, 0.1835]\nPeriodicSite: B (1.7232, 1.3041, 9.3358) [0.5000, 0.2204, 0.8165]\nPeriodicSite: B (1.7232, 2.1437, 5.3450) [0.5000, 0.3622, 0.4675]\nPeriodicSite: B (1.7232, 3.7743, 6.0891) [0.5000, 0.6378, 0.5325]\nPeriodicSite: B (1.7232, 5.1028, 0.3721) [0.5000, 0.8622, 0.0325]\nPeriodicSite: B (1.7232, 0.8153, 11.0621) [0.5000, 0.1378, 0.9675])",
        "('structure', Structure Summary\nLattice\n    abc : 3.738665247991437 3.738665247991437 3.61051776\n angles : 90.0 90.0 106.27565704267273\n volume : 48.44396724150258\n      A : 2.24279581 -2.99123466 0.0\n      B : 2.24279581 2.99123466 0.0\n      C : 0.0 0.0 3.61051776\nPeriodicSite: Y (2.2428, 2.9725, 0.0000) [0.0031, 0.9969, -0.0000]\nPeriodicSite: Ni (2.2428, -0.6786, 1.8053) [0.6134, 0.3866, 0.5000]\nPeriodicSite: C (2.9274, 1.1773, 1.8053) [0.4558, 0.8494, 0.5000]\nPeriodicSite: C (1.5582, 1.1773, 1.8053) [0.1506, 0.5442, 0.5000])",
    ]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(ex_dict)
```

Here is one way to do it with Pandas [str.extract](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) (using a [regex](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html) pattern) and [concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```py
new_df = pd.concat(
    [df, df["structure"].str.extract(r"[abc]{3} : (\d+\.\d+) (\d+\.\d+) (\d+\.\d+)")],
    axis=1,
).rename(columns={0: "a", 1: "b", 2: "c"})
```

Then:

```py
print(new_df)
# Output
                                                                                                                                                                            
             structure                  a                  b            c
0  ('structure', St...         3.44648958         5.91809299  11.43413371
1  ('structure', St...  3.738665247991437  3.738665247991437   3.61051776
```